# UDEV rule to run partprobe on loop device

Tags: udev, loop-device, udisks

I use udisks2 to mount raw image over a loop device:

```
udisksctl -f image.img --no-user-interaction
```

Policykit is configured, so no errors here. For some reason kernel does not want to re-read partition table, when loop0 device changes. I try to create an UDEV rule to force it with `partprobe`. This is what I tried so far:

```
KERNEL=="loop0", RUN+="sleep 2;/sbin/partprobe /dev/loop0"
```

If I do not place delay before partprobe, then udisks catches timeout in loop-setup. But the rule still does not function.

My kernel is:

Linux acceptance 3.16-2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.3-2 (2014-09-20) x86_64 GNU/Linux

I would love to have UDEV rules corrected or other method to force the kernel re-reading the partition table. A call to udisks is a part of a rather big script, which I would not like to modify specifically for Debian.

Comment: Does `partprobe` work as expected when called manually outside of the UDEV rule?